#  SC Java Programmer 6 exam

Tags: java

there is program from exam. Could anyone explain how "-434" is the answer:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
public class ComingThru {
    static String s = "-";
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        A[] aa = new A[2];
        B[] ba = new B[2];
        sifter(aa);
        sifter(ba);
        sifter(7);
        System.out.print(s);
    }
    static void sifter(A[]... a2) { s += "1";}
    static void sifter(B[]... b1) { s += "2";}
    static void sifter(B[] b1)    { s += "3";}
    static void sifter(Object o)  { s += "4";}
}
```

Thank  you!

Comment: I guess it will call : 
sifter(Object o) for sifter(aa)
sifter(B[] b1] for sifter(ba)
sifter(Object o) for sifter(7)

Comment: @skaffman: yeah, that code should be taken out back and shot.

Comment: @Roman cap? what does that mean?

Comment: @skaffman well, it tests understanding of yet another obscure feature in Java, so that when you see such a code in a real life, you'd not only WTFed, but rewritten it without errors. Reminds of a real price of the syntax sugar, too.

Comment: So dear user, could you please explain which of `-`, `4`, `3`, and `4` is of concern to you—and why?

Comment: Don't close the question. It doesn't matter if you like the code or not, it is a legitimate question worth an answer.

Comment: @Paul: It's a legit question, but (and maybe I'm an idealist here), I think that the user should show evidence of ***some*** effort towards solving this first, don't you think? Otherwise it smells of being a homework dump.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, this one had me scratching my head too, even after reading the JLS (which is normally clear to me). I don't know what I'd say to this other than, "WTF??".

Answer (score 7):

You probably know that when calling a method that appears with several different sets of parameters, Java will try to call the one that is **most specific**. So, for example, the `sifter(Object)` method can apply to any object, but if the object is known to be a `B[]`, the more specific `sifter(B[])` method will be called instead.

The tricky bit is that in order to ensure backwards compatibility, when Java is trying to figure out what method to call, it first looks to see if there is **any** applicable non-varargs method. Only if there is no such method will it consider a varargs option.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2

So, when calling `sifter()` with an `A[]`, the non-varargs method `sifter(Object)` is applicable, and so the compiler never even considers `sifter(A[]...)`.

Comment: By the way, this is **not** a fair question. Even though you gave the answer I had to read the JLS to see why it happened. And you will hopefully never encounter a situation like this in real life - no sane API designer would allow a class to have two methods that are ambiguous in this way.

Comment: +1 for giving the real reason for this strange behaviour

Comment: As proof of this, remove `static void sifter(Object o)  { s += "4";}` (and `sifter(7);`) and you'll find `sifter(A[]... a2)` is called. For even more fun, add this to the code: `A[][] aa2 = new A[1][1]; aa2[0] = aa; sifter(aa2);` - this will call the first `sifter`, not the last. I'm still working on why that is...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler resolves method calls using the following rules: (not mentioning declaration/visibility scopes)
1,  If an exact signature match exists, the call resolves to that method.
2a, If the parameter is a primitive, it tries to box it in case there is no match. 
2b, If no match exists it tries to widen which means it will look for declarations with the supertype of the actual parameter type.
3, If no widened signature match exists, it will try to match varargs. 
If still no match occurs, that means a compile-time error.(The steps 2a and 2b are mutually exclusive)
Based on these rules:
`-` because of the initialization
The call `sifter(aa);` resolves to the `Object` argumented method because the compiler first tries to widen. `sifter(ba);` resolves to the `B[]` arg-ed method because it is an exact signature match, then the last again resolves to the `Object` method, the rule is again that the compiler first tries to widen, then tries the varargs. So the final result is `434` for the method calls.

Answer (score -1):

You possibly think the answer is -134. But it is actually -434.

Last "4" comes from the argument "7" and it only corresponds to the one with **Object** parameter.

"3" corresponds to the directly static **void sifter(B[] b1)**.

The reason of first "4" is nearest parameter is Object, becuase "(A[]... a2)" is not valid.
If it was **"(A... a2)"** , then -134 would have been correct.

Comment: No, this is not correct. `(A[]... a2)` is valid.

Comment: I wanted to mean it is not valid for that argument. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much for your input, it's very helpful. I'm learning Java on my own and was startled by the answer -434(after reading the book for 3 h), not by the question and had no idea where even to start. This is not homework, it's from the book on the exam SCJP6, p.181 by Bates. I apologize if I broke some rules here. Pray for leniency as a newbee here. Thanks again

Comment: I don't think that book is the best source for a complete beginner, rather read the java tutorials on oracle's webpage. They are complete, up to date and cover all important aspects and much more from the java API. Btw this answer is incorrect.